# Problema com ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-router

Estou com problema de fazer um POST utilizando o ui-sref. Eu preciso chamar um controller passando um ID onde vai me retornar os dados gravados no banco. Funciona muito bem quando utilizo route, porem quando vou utilizar o ui.route estou tendo problema.

Com o ngRouter

```
.when("/highways/:id",
        {
            templateUrl: "assets/templates/highway/edit.html",
            controller: "HighwayController",
            controllerAs: "ctrl"
        })
```

Com o ui.router

```
.state('highways.id', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/highway/edit.html',
        controller: 'HighwayController as ctrl'


    })
```

Chamada no html

```
<tr ng-repeat="hw in ctrl.search.results" ui-sref="highways.id(hw)">
    <!--ng-click="ctrl.search.redirectToItem(hw)"-->
```

Esse ng-click é a chamada que estava funcionando antes de que usar o ui.router.

Answer (score 2):

Por favor, tente da seguinte maneira:

```
<tr ng-repeat="hw in ctrl.search.results" ui-sref="highways.id({id: hw})">
```

Comment: Fiz, porém não chama nem o outro template onde os dados devem ser carregados.

Comment: Será que não é nenhuma configuração que precisa ser feito dentro do $state highway.id ?